# Xcode15 archives application and white screen when entering the application with low version iOS

Tags: ios, angularjs, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

I updated to Xcode 15 and I use it to archive an application. The application runs with a white screen on iPhones with iOS below 16.6. On 16.6 or 17.0 the application runs normally. I don't know what's wrong with it. I used iOS SDK17. Is this version too high?

The project framework is angularjs and ionic and uses Cordova to compile it to an iOS project. My Cordova version is 6.2.0.

I changed deployment version and try to connect iPhone to debug but failed. I want to know how to solve white screen problem.